# Расстояние между элементами ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

**Желаемый результат выглядит так:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
XAML:
<StackPanel Name="SPName" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

---

```
C#:
mass = new Rectangle[100];
for (int i = 0; i < Mass.Length; i++)
{
      mass[i] = new Rectangle();
      mass[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
      mass[i].Width = SList.ActualWidth / Mass.Length;
      mass[i].Height = (SList.ActualHeight - 100) * (i / 100.0);
      mass[i].Fill = Brushes.Green;
      mass[i].StrokeThickness = 1;
      mass[i].Stroke = Brushes.Black;

      SPName.Children.Add(mass[i]);
}
```

**При реализации через ListBox получается это:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
XAML:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mass}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
C#:
Panel parent = ((sender as Button).Parent as Panel).Parent as Panel;
mass = new Rectangle[100];
for (int i = 0; i < Mass.Length; i++)
{
        mass[i] = new Rectangle();
        mass[i].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        mass[i].Width = parent.ActualWidth / Mass.Length;
        mass[i].Height = (parent.ActualHeight - 100) * (i / 100.0);
        mass[i].Fill = Brushes.Green;
        mass[i].StrokeThickness = 1;
        mass[i].Stroke = Brushes.Black;
}
OnPropertyChanged("Mass");
```

Как реализовать первый вариант с помощью ListBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно это:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mass}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Green"
                       Height="{Binding}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

При этом ваш `Mass` имеет тип `double[]` или там `IEnumerable<double>` и содержит нужные высоты прямоугольников.

Получается вот такой результат:

[image: зелёный треугольник]

---

Если вам нужен `ListView`, вам придётся ещё подправить стиль контейнера:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mass}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Green"
                       Height="{Binding}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Все так как хотелось, большое спасибо! Однако нет возможности выделить конкретный столбец (выделяются сразу все). Может вы подскажите как это изменить?

SelectionMode="Single" пробовал

Comment: @лалалалала: Чтобы можно было выделить, используйте `ListBox`, т. к. у `ItemsControl` нету выделеннного элемента.

Comment: @VladD, но стоит заменить на ListBox и картинка превращается в такую же как у автора. Выравнивание по центру. Ширина минимальная. Отступы между элементами...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ах вот оно что! Надо посмотреть!.. Спасибо.

Comment: @лалалалала: Обновил ответ.

Comment: VлалалалалаdD :)

Comment: @alexolut: Да-да? :)

Comment: Ща вопрос задам скоро по шарпам :)